# jQuery PickMeUp datepicker: disable array of dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using a jQuery datepicker plugin called [**PickMeUp**](https://github.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp).

I have the datepicker working but can't work out how to disable dates in it. My plan is to have an array of dates that would be disabled on the datepicker calendar.

I did manage to disable one date using the documentation from a previous version of the plugin, (http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/), but I can't figure out how to add an array of dates to it.

### jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        var now2 = new Date();
        now2.addDays(-1);
        now2.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        $('input#cdate').pickmeup({
        position  : 'right',                                        
            mode      : 'range',                        
            render: function(date) {
                return {
                    disabled: date.valueOf() == now2.valueOf()                          
                }
            }                           
        }); 
    });
```

---

### Update

Below is the working code. (Many, many thanks to [Niloct](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152016/niloct))

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        var arDates = [new Date("2014-02-14").valueOf(),new Date("2014-02-11").valueOf(),new Date("2014-02-09").valueOf()];
        $('input#cdate').pickmeup({
        position  : 'right',                                        
            mode      : 'range',                        
            render: function(date) {
                return {
                    disabled: arDates.indexOf(date.valueOf()) != -1                         
                }
            }                           
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Say you have an array `arDates` of Dates, each one with `.valueOf()` instead of the objects, what happens if you say `disabled: arDates.indexOf(date.valueOf()) != -1` in last line ?

Comment: Ok... how would I write the array? Like this? `var arDates = ["2014-02-14","2014-02-11","2014-02-10"];`

Comment: Instead of date strings, set e.g. `new Date("2014-02-14").valueOf()` for first one. Does your calendar have time too ? Try this first.

Comment: Haha that seems to do it!!! Thank you so much :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just writing it down:

`valueOf()` is one of the methods of [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods) object that gets the number of milliseconds in a date (since 01/01/1970).

`indexOf()` is a method of the [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) object that checks if an element is a member of an array.

So your first code is spot on, also you got the tweaks:

```
var arDates = [new Date("2014-02-14").valueOf(),new Date("2014-02-11").valueOf(),new Date("2014-02-09").valueOf()];

disabled: arDates.indexOf(date.valueOf()) != -1
```

What you **may** face is issues with timezones. For instance: `new Date("2014-02-17")` for me does not create a date in Feb 17th. It falls back 3 hours due to my timezone.

Answer (score 1):

You've clearly already solved this issue but, for future reference, here's a little extension to the problem in which also a new class is added to the array of dates. This because `PickMeUp`'s default color-scheme for disabled dates is black; this makes it hard to see them. Besides, I've included a little hack to deselect the current date. This because, by default, `PickMeUp` selects the current date and this might not be desirable.

The following **Javascript/jQuery** achieves what you want:

```
// Creating some 'sample' dates 
var datesArray = [];
var d = new Date();
for (i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
    var tempDay = new Date(); tempDay.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    tempDay.setDate(d.getDate()+i);
    datesArray.push(tempDay.getTime());
}

$(function () {
    $('.multiple').pickmeup({
        flat: true,
        mode: 'multiple',
        // Before rendering each date, deselect dates if in the array
        render: function(date) {
            if ($.inArray(date.getTime(), datesArray) > -1){
                return {
                    disabled   : true,
                    class_name : 'disabled'
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
// Little hack to deselect current day: PickMeUp forces you to have a default date :(
$('.pmu-today').click();
```

With the following **CSS** to make it look more intuitive:

```
.disabled {
    color: #5C5C8A !important;
    background: #000033;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n5xtn75y/)