# Jquery put dates into array

Tags: jquery

I'm querying a google calendar using json, then posting the resulting data to a php file using ajax, which formats the dates, then returns them as the following string of arrays:

```
["2014-03-06"]["2014-05-01","2014-05-02","2014-05-03","2014-05-04","2014-05-05"]["2014-02-21"]
```

I then need to get this string of arrays and somehow make it into this:

```
var arDates = [new Date("2014-02-21").valueOf(),new Date("2014-03-06").valueOf(),new Date("2014-05-01").valueOf(),new Date("2014-05-02").valueOf(),new Date("2014-05-03").valueOf(),new Date("2014-05-04").valueOf(),new Date("2014-05-05").valueOf()];
```

... so that I can disable some dates in a jquery datepicker.

This question follows on from a previous question i posted - [jQuery PickMeUp datepicker: disable array of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841481/jquery-datepicker-disabled-array-of-dates)

Any ideas how I do this please? Full code below: (including a few things i've already tried unsuccessfully.

```
        $j=jQuery.noConflict(); 
        $j(document).ready(function(){                      
            var eventName = '';
            var gclaData = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/hello%40freestretch.co.uk/public/basic?orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&max-results=8&futureevents=true&alt=json';
            $j.getJSON(gclaData,function(data){
                for(var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++){
                    eventName += data.feed.entry[i].summary.$t+"</br>";
                }                                   
                $j.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'myprocess.php',
                    data: {'dates': eventName},
                    success: function(gcdates) {
                        // returned data is: ["2014-03-06"]["2014-05-01","2014-05-02","2014-05-03","2014-05-04","2014-05-05"]["2014-02-21"]
                        var str = gcdates.replace(/]/g, ",");
                        str = str.replace(/\[/g, "");
                        var lastChar = str.slice(-1);
                        if(lastChar == ',') {
                            str = str.slice(0, -1);
                        }                                   
                        //var match = str.split(',');
                        //console.log(str)
                        /*for (var a in match){
                            var mynewdate = match[a];
                            //mynewdate = 'new Date(' + mynewdate + ').valueOf()';
                            //console.log(mynewdate)
                        }   */
                        //console.log(str);                     
                        var arDates = [new Date("2014-02-21").valueOf(),new Date("2014-03-06").valueOf(),new Date("2014-05-01").valueOf(),new Date("2014-05-02").valueOf(),new Date("2014-05-03").valueOf(),new Date("2014-05-04").valueOf(),new Date("2014-05-05").valueOf()];
                        //console.log(arDates)                                              
                        $j('input#cdate').pickmeup({
                            position  : 'right',                                        
                            mode      : 'range',                            
                            render: function(date) {
                                return {                                    
                                    disabled: arDates.indexOf(date.valueOf()) != -1                             
                                }
                            }                           
                        });                                     
                    }
                });           
            }); 
        });
```

Comment: What format are your dates in?  Strings?  An array of strings?  How are you getting the dates?  What have you tried?  What are you stuck on?  What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Why is jquery needed here?  A simple loop can solve this

```
var source = ["2014-03-06","2014-05-01","2014-05-02"];
var dest = [];
for (var i in source) {
  dest.push(new Date(i).valueOf());
}
```